# Function repeating forever

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, while-loop, slice

keeps on running through the loop even though the while loop condition should turn it off?

```
userinput = str(input(''))  

def input_read() :
    newstring1 = []
    EB_to_01 = []
    placeholder = 0
    y = 0

    while y <= len(userinput) :
        for i in userinput[y:] :
            if i != 'E' and i != 'B' :
                newstring1.append(i)
                y += 1
            else : break

        placeholder += 1

        for i in userinput[y:]:
            if i == 'E' :
                newstring1.append(placeholder)
                EB_to_01.append(i)
                y += 1
            elif i == 'B' :
                newstring1.append(placeholder)
                EB_to_01.append(i)
                y += 1
            else: break
    
    print(newstring1 ,'\n',EB_to_01)
    return EB_to_01


input_read()
```

I tried removing the slicing on the for loops and it doesn't endlessly repeat. I need the slicing though because in short I'mm trying to add all E's and B's into a separate list and replace all E's and B's in the input with numbers in the order they are in the string.

Comment: Why do you think that the while loop condition should stop the loop?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Because y is eventually going to reach the number of characters in the input because every time a value is added to newstring1 it also adds 1 to y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition of the while loop should be < and not <= because the loop starts at y = 0 and ends at one less than the length so never reaches the stop condition.

One handy tool when you have endless loops is putting in print statements at key points (like indexes) to see what's happening.